# How do I add a button to the Safari toolbar that, when clicked, executes a given AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, applescript, safari-extension

Basically want to run a shell command from that script .
Is this possible ?

Please answer me . I m new in mac development.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Safari extension, but here's an idea. Create an applet and edit the plist to give it its own bundle identifier, e.g. com.yourname.myfunnyscript. Now create a simple link that downloads a tiny 1 byte file with a unique file extension, e.g. myfile.myfunnyscript. Tell Safari to automatically open the file with your applet. This should cause your applet to run. You can drag the link into your bookmarks bar.